# 4 agora in-call statistics methods are not logging anything

Tags: agora.io

We followed the [official documentation](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/call_statistics_web?platform=Web) of implementation of in-call statistics reporting. The methods, `getLocalAudioStats`, `getLocalVideoStats`, `getRemoteAudioStats`, & `getRemoteAudioStats` are not logging anything.

We have searched the official documentation but have not found any resolution.

Here is our code:

```
              client.getLocalAudioStats((localAudioStats) => {                
    for(var uid in localAudioStats){
         console.log(`Audio CodecType from ${uid}: ${localAudioStats[uid].CodecType}`);
         console.log(`Audio MuteState from ${uid}: ${localAudioStats[uid].MuteState}`);
         console.log(`Audio RecordingLevel from ${uid}: ${localAudioStats[uid].RecordingLevel}`);
         console.log(`Audio SamplingRate from ${uid}: ${localAudioStats[uid].SamplingRate}`);
         console.log(`Audio SendBitrate from ${uid}: ${localAudioStats[uid].SendBitrate}`);
         console.log(`Audio SendLevel from ${uid}: ${localAudioStats[uid].SendLevel}`);
    }
});

              client.getLocalVideoStats((localVideoStats) => {
    for(var uid in localVideoStats){
         console.log(`Video CaptureFrameRate from ${uid}: ${localVideoStats[uid].CaptureFrameRate}`);
         console.log(`Video CaptureResolutionHeight from ${uid}: ${localVideoStats[uid].CaptureResolutionHeight}`);
         console.log(`Video CaptureResolutionWidth from ${uid}: ${localVideoStats[uid].CaptureResolutionWidth}`);
         console.log(`Video EncodeDelay from ${uid}: ${localVideoStats[uid].EncodeDelay}`);
         console.log(`Video MuteState from ${uid}: ${localVideoStats[uid].MuteState}`);
         console.log(`Video SendBitrate from ${uid}: ${localVideoStats[uid].SendBitrate}`);
         console.log(`Video SendFrameRate from ${uid}: ${localVideoStats[uid].SendFrameRate}`);
         console.log(`Video SendResolutionHeight from ${uid}: ${localVideoStats[uid].SendResolutionHeight}`);
         console.log(`Video SendResolutionWidth from ${uid}: ${localVideoStats[uid].SendResolutionWidth}`);
         console.log(`Video TargetSendBitrate from ${uid}: ${localVideoStats[uid].TargetSendBitrate}`);
         console.log(`Video TotalDuration from ${uid}: ${localVideoStats[uid].TotalDuration}`);
         console.log(`Video TotalFreezeTime from ${uid}: ${localVideoStats[uid].TotalFreezeTime}`);
    }
});

              client.getRemoteAudioStats((remoteAudioStatsMap) => {
    for(var uid in remoteAudioStatsMap){
         console.log(`Audio CodecType from ${uid}: ${remoteAudioStatsMap[uid].CodecType}`);
         console.log(`Audio End2EndDelay from ${uid}: ${remoteAudioStatsMap[uid].End2EndDelay}`);
         console.log(`Audio MuteState from ${uid}: ${remoteAudioStatsMap[uid].MuteState}`);
         console.log(`Audio PacketLossRate from ${uid}: ${remoteAudioStatsMap[uid].PacketLossRate}`);
         console.log(`Audio RecvBitrate from ${uid}: ${remoteAudioStatsMap[uid].RecvBitrate}`);
         console.log(`Audio RecvLevel from ${uid}: ${remoteAudioStatsMap[uid].RecvLevel}`);
         console.log(`Audio TotalFreezeTime from ${uid}: ${remoteAudioStatsMap[uid].TotalFreezeTime}`);
         console.log(`Audio TotalPlayDuration from ${uid}: ${remoteAudioStatsMap[uid].TotalPlayDuration}`);
         console.log(`Audio TransportDelay from ${uid}: ${remoteAudioStatsMap[uid].TransportDelay}`);
    }
});

              client.getRemoteVideoStats((remoteVideoStatsMap) => {
    for(var uid in remoteVideoStatsMap){
         console.log(`Video End2EndDelay from ${uid}: ${remoteVideoStatsMap[uid].End2EndDelay}`);
         console.log(`Video MuteState from ${uid}: ${remoteVideoStatsMap[uid].MuteState}`);
         console.log(`Video PacketLossRate from ${uid}: ${remoteVideoStatsMap[uid].PacketLossRate}`);
         console.log(`Video RecvBitrate from ${uid}: ${remoteVideoStatsMap[uid].RecvBitrate}`);
         console.log(`Video RecvResolutionHeight from ${uid}: ${remoteVideoStatsMap[uid].RecvResolutionHeight}`);
         console.log(`Video RecvResolutionWidth from ${uid}: ${remoteVideoStatsMap[uid].RecvResolutionWidth}`);
         console.log(`Video RenderFrameRate from ${uid}: ${remoteVideoStatsMap[uid].RenderFrameRate}`);
         console.log(`Video RenderResolutionHeight from ${uid}: ${remoteVideoStatsMap[uid].RenderResolutionHeight}`);
         console.log(`Video RenderResolutionWidth from ${uid}: ${remoteVideoStatsMap[uid].RenderResolutionWidth}`);
         console.log(`Video TotalFreezeTime from ${uid}: ${remoteVideoStatsMap[uid].TotalFreezeTime}`);
         console.log(`Video TotalPlayDuration from ${uid}: ${remoteVideoStatsMap[uid].TotalPlayDuration}`);
         console.log(`Video TransportDelay from ${uid}: ${remoteVideoStatsMap[uid].TransportDelay}`);
    }
});
```

We expect to see output from the `console.log` statements. We don't see any output.

Comment: What browser are you using? According to the documentation these methods only work on Google Chrome and can take up to 3 seconds for the logs to appear.

Comment: Look ad the disclaimer just above the title this link goes to https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/call_statistics_web?platform=Web#get-the-statistics-of-the-remote-stream